# Reading json content from file to do assertion functional testing in SOUP UI using Groovy scripts

Tags: json, testing, groovy, soapui, assertion

I am using [SOAP UI](http://www.soapui.org/About-SoapUI/what-is-soapui.html) to test the [RESTful](http://www.soapui.org/REST-Testing/getting-started.html) web services. To automate the regression testing, I need to compare the actual response and expected output. I have the actual response to the request parsed into a json object. I have the expected output in a text file with JSON content.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper 
def response = messageExchange.response.responseContent
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def responseAsJsonObject = slurper.parseText response

//? Read json file content and parse it as an json object

assert fileContentAsJsonObject == responseAsJsonObject
```

I need a way to read this JSON content from the text file and parse into a json object in *Groovy*.

Comment: JsonSlurper has a parse method for parsing file - use it.

Comment: Thanks, but my problem was reading file content.

Answer (score 0):

```
def fileContent = new File('D:\\test.json').text
def fileContentAsJsonObject = slurper.parseText fileContent
```

It works! Get the file content using .text and parse the fileContent to the jsonSlurper, which generates you the json object.

Its better to use log.info to write on log console and debugg.